# Difference between MFKey32V1 and MFKey32V2

Tags: nfc, mifare

I'm wondering what the difference between MFKey32V1 and MFKey32V2 (for Mifare Card, on both Proxmark 3 and Chameleon)?

it seems like V2 need to collect 2 nonces, but V1 only need to collect one ([Please see mfkey32.c and mfkey32v2.c here](https://github.com/RfidResearchGroup/ChameleonUltra/tree/main/software/src))? What's the benefits of each version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fun thing,
the version 1 needs two consecutive authentication attempts from the same time.  ie cryptostream is in following order.

the version 2 improves this by bypassing the time restraint and you only need two authentication attempts regardless of when they were collected.  Its a great improvement.